# Why does the list of images change rapidly in my Image composable

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to get a list of images from an API on the web and display it in an image composable (using coil) on my Home Screen. I want the image to change randomly everytime the user reopens the app since it's a list but it changes rapidly instead.

Immidiately the app opens, it starts chaginging randomly but rapidly with unclear time intervals.
Tried using debounce but didn't work.

ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class MealViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: MealRepository
): ViewModel() {
    fun getRandomMeal(): Flow<String?> = flow {
        val randomMeal = repository.getRandomMeal()
        val meal = randomMeal.body()?.meals?.firstOrNull()?.strMealThumb
        if (meal != null) {
            Log.i("randomMealVM", meal)
        }
        emit(meal)
    }
}
```

How i collected in the Home Screen

```
val viewModel = hiltViewModel<MealViewModel>()
val randomMeal = viewModel.getRandomMeal().collectAsState(initial = null)

 Box (
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(160.dp)
                .width(330.dp)
                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
        ){
            AsyncImage(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize(),
                model = randomMeal.value,
                contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                contentDescription = "Random Food Image"
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think part of your problem is that `getRandomMeal()` returns a new Flow instance each time it's called, so on recomposition a new State is the one getting collected so it restarts the Flow collection. Even if it returned the same instance every time, the compiler probably wouldn't be sophisticated enough to tell. To make that work, you'd probably need to change `getRandomMeal()` to a `val` property with no custom getter implementation to make it [stable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/performance/stability).

But anyway `getRandomMeal()` is nonsensical. A Flow isn't really a "flow" if it only emits a single item. That should just be a suspend function that directly returns the String. And then in the composable you would use

```
val randomMeal = produceState(initialValue = null, Unit) { viewModel.getRandomMeal() }
```

I think this might fix the problem of the image rapidly changing, but I think you would still have some other lurking issue that's causing recompositions that isn't obvious in the code you have shared--might be elsewhere in your whole composition.

Comment: I tried your answer but the Images are not displaying at all now

Comment: I would have to see more of your code and how you implemented my answer to speculate what's wrong.

Comment: hi, i got it to work. I used a suspend function that returns the string for the getRandomMeal function like you said and called it in the HomeScreen composable within a coroutine using the LaunchedEffect composable. Thanks for your help